# Datastax Enterprise v 4.8.4 and Solr numCount

Tags: datastax-enterprise

Using Datastax enterprise 4.8.4 - I'm trying to do a simple pagination based on the indexed records that are successfully indexed into Solr. The problem I have is that to do this simple pagination (without deep pagination as results are typically < 1000) - I used the numCount to prepare a JSON response with the available results found. Using the native datastax drivers (e.g. without using Solr-HTTP) - I could not find an example of how to fetch numCount from a Solr query. Is fetching numCount even possible from Datastax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 4.8 versions Solr `numFound` is only reachable via a `SELECT count(*) ... FROM ... WHERE solr_query=...`

Solr `numFound` support will be improved in the future though.

Comment: Thanks for this. As a work around I wrote a direct SOLR HTTP request, but thanks for the tip. As I recall, I've read somewhere that it was recommended to go straight to SOLR. I was using the PhantomDSL wrapper to manage my mappings so I believe that was also hampering my ability to fetch numCount natively. Will revisit this solution once the support is better for a unified search through the API.